# sort teams for ranking sport_league by matchs

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a table(query&php) like this for a sports ranking page:
i have 4 team in table:

> how sort teams by point when pionts is equal AND team4 is better , 
>   because it is winner of 2 matchs team3 vs team4 ?

```
  ------------------------------------------
  --Data setup
  ------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE Teams (
  id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  rank  INT(10),
  win   INT(10) NOT NULL,
  loss  INT(10) NOT NULL,
  tie   INT(10) NOT NULL,
  dgoals INT(10) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Matchs (
  mid INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  home       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  away       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  homescore  INT(10) NOT NULL,
  awayscore  INT(10) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Matchs (home, away, homescore, awayscore)
VALUES 
      ('Team1','Team2',2,1),('Team2','Team1',1,1),
      ('Team3','Team4',3,2),('Team4','Team3',5,1),
      ('Team1','Team3',1,1),('Team3','Team1',1,1),
      ('Team2','Team4',1,1),('Team4','Team2',1,1),
      ('Team1','Team4',1,1),('Team4','Team1',1,1),
      ('Team2','Team3',1,1),('Team3','Team2',1,1)


INSERT INTO Teams (name, win, loss, tie, point, dgoals)
VALUES 
      ('Team1',1,0,5,8,1),
      ('Team2',0,1,5,5,-1),
      ('Team3',1,1,4,7,-3),
      ('Team4',1,1,4,7,3)

  ------------------------------------------
  --Answer
  ------------------------------------------
$result = $db->query("SELECT id,name, point FROM Teams ORDER BY point DESC"); 
$rank=1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo "<tr><td>".$rank."</td><td>".$row["name"]." ".$row["point"]."</td></tr>";
 $rank++;
}
  ------------------------------------------
   --Question
  ------------------------------------------

how sort teams by point when pionts is equal AND team4 is better , 
because it is winner of 2 matchs team3 vs team4 ?
```

for example :
i want sort by point but team2 and team3 have equal points
for this example team2 is winner of sum(matchs) with team3, so team2 have btter rank, , output is rank , how get rank for this?

```
Team   rank   W   L   T   point  goals  
—————————————————————————————————————
Team2    ?    6   2   2   20     +8 
Team3    ?    6   2   2   20     +8


matchs   home   away   score_h   score_a     
—————————————————————————————————————————
match1   team2  team3    2         1    
match2   team3  team2    1         1
```

Comment: What's the expected output out of this data?

Comment: Just to be clear - you have the second (matches) table and are trying to produce the first table, right?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question. Actually your result is already sorted by points. You can use `ORDER DESC BY` clause in SQL.

Comment: output is rank Column

Comment: @Mureinik, yes its true

Comment: Since I (and probably many others) do not know much about sports, you should explain more details about how calculations are to be done. (with example situations)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone my problem for when points is Equal,

Comment: How are the points calculated, and what exactly is expected, when the teams have 20p. in this table and why? What is +-g? Show you PHP/SQL so far.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone for any matchs winner get 3 point , losser get 0 point ,  Tie get 1 point; this table for example , i want get outpot rank of this table , all column is ready , i want just output ranking sort by point

Comment: Ok, it becomes clearer... Could it somehow happen in this comparison, that Team2 seems better than Team3, Team3 better than Team4, but also Team4 better than Team2? (+1 for question edits)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone yes, its true , Because in the game with opponent is winner

Comment: Maybe you or some other might get inspired by [Wikipedia basic calculation principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Football_Elo_Ratings#Basic_calculation_principles). It could become a high voted good question if you add your PHP & SQL code so far.

Comment: Refer also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone my PHP & SQL code is very long and many parts, but ok , i try add simple of it,

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone i edited question and add simple php /sql code ,